# Print 10 most infrequent words of a text document using python

Tags: python, python-2.6, defaultdict

I have a small python script that prints the 10 most frequent words of a text document (with each word being 2 letters or more) and I need to continue the script to print the 10 most INfrequent words in the document as well. I have a script that is relatively working, except the 10 most infrequent words it prints are numbers (integers and floaters) when they should be words. How can I iterate ONLY words and exclude the numbers? Here is my full script:

```
# Most Frequent Words:
from string import punctuation
from collections import defaultdict

number = 10
words = {}

with open("charactermask.txt") as txt_file:
    words = [x.strip(punctuation).lower() for x in txt_file.read().split()]

counter = defaultdict(int)

for word in words:
  if len(word) >= 2:
    counter[word] += 1

top_words = sorted(counter.iteritems(),
                    key=lambda(word, count): (-count, word))[:number] 

for word, frequency in top_words:
    print "%s: %d" % (word, frequency)


# Least Frequent Words:
least_words = sorted(counter.iteritems(),
                    key=lambda (word, count): (count, word))[:number]

for word, frequency in least_words:
    print "%s: %d" % (word, frequency)
```

**EDIT:** The end of the document (the part under the `# Least Frequent Words` comment) is the part that needs fixing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to need a filter -- change the regex to match however you want to define a "word":

```
import re
alphaonly = re.compile(r"^[a-z]{2,}$")
```

Now, do you want the word frequency table to *not include numbers* in the first place?

```
counter = defaultdict(int)

with open("charactermask.txt") as txt_file:
    for line in txt_file:
        for word in line.strip().split():
          word = word.strip(punctuation).lower()
          if alphaonly.match(word):
              counter[word] += 1
```

Or do you just want to *skip over the numbers* when extracting the least-frequent words from the table?

```
words_by_freq = sorted(counter.iteritems(),
                       key=lambda(word, count): (count, word))

i = 0
for word, frequency in words_by_freq:
    if alphaonly.match(word):
        i += 1
        sys.stdout.write("{}: {}\n".format(word, frequency))
    if i == number: break
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a function, `letters_only()`, which will run a regular expression matching `[0-9]` and, if any matches are found, return False.  Something like this::

```
def letters_only(word):
    return re.search(r'[0-9]', word) is None
```

Then, where you say `for word in words`, instead say `for word in filter(letters_only, words)`.

Comment: Great.  Also changed my answer to the shorter form suggested by wim; I think the longer form is clearer, but perhaps it's just a code tic I need to exorcise. :)  Slightly baffled by the downvote, but so it goes.